# List of unique headers recursively on files matching pattern

Tags: python, bash, grep, xargs, unix-head

I want the unique headers for a bunch of `csv` files whose names contain `ABC` or `XYZ`.

Within a single directory, I can sort of get what I need with:

```sh
head -n ` *.csv > first.txt
cat -A first.txt | tr ',' '\n' | sort | uniq
```

Of course, this isn't recursive and it includes *all* `csv` files, not just the ones I want.

If I do the following, I get the recursive search, but also a bunch of junk:

```sh
find . -type f -name "ABC*.csv" -o -name "XYZ*.csv" | xargs head -n 1 | tr ',' '\n' | sort | uniq
```

I'm on Windows 10 with MinGW64.  I suppose I could use Python, but I feel so close to having it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `head` is given multiple files (`xargs` does that) it prints their names as well.

Using `find`'s `-exec` action (you should force the precedence of `-name 'ABC*.csv' -o -name 'XYZ*.csv` for it to work) you can obtain the desired result. `uniq` is also not required here, sort can do that on its own. And as a sidenote, you better enclose literal strings in single quotes.

```
find . -type f \( -name 'ABC*.csv' -o -name 'XYZ*.csv' \) -exec head -n 1 {} \; | tr ',' '\n' | sort -u
```

If your files have DOS line endings above command will not work though. In that case you should delete carriage returns using `tr` or `sed`:

```
find . -type f \( -name 'ABC*.csv' -o -name 'XYZ*.csv' \) -exec head -n 1 {} \; | tr -d '\r' | tr ',' '\n' | sort -u
# or
find . -type f \( -name 'ABC*.csv' -o -name 'XYZ*.csv' \) -exec head -n 1 {} \; | sed 's/\r//; s/,/\n/g' | sort -u
```

Comment: Hmm, it seems to not return all results.  Searching only `ABC*.csv` turns up different headers than when both `ABC` and `XYZ` are searched.

Comment: Different results as well. :/

Comment: When using the `cat -A` approach, I noticed that some headers have junk in them. For example, `First Name` and `First Name^M`.

Comment: Still not returning some known headers.  I do have `sed`, though.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't provide the files :(  I sincerely appreciate your assistance.  I learned a few things and, if I'm losing my mind, at least I'm not alone!

Comment: A note for future me, if you need a more complex regex, do something like `find . -type f -regextype posix-extended -regex '.*/(ABC|XYZ)[0-9]+.csv'`.  The leading `.*/` is needed because `find` returns the absolute path.  The different regextype syntaxes are described here: https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/Regular-Expressions.html